# How can I count groupings?

Tags: mysql, sql

Sorry for the bad title, but I'm having trouble explaining what I'm trying to do without an example:

Let's say I have a table that is about product sales, and I have columns representing a customerID, and a stateID for that customer.  I want to know, for each state, what are the most frequent customers.

A table might look like this:

```
CustomerID   StateID
----------   -------
1            MD
1            VA
1            MD
2            NC
2            NC
3            MD
3            VA
3            NC
3            VA
...          ...
```

I'm not even sure if an SQL query is capable of producing this result.  By I want a query that will tell me that for MD customer 1 is most frequent, For VA, customer 3 is most frequent, and it's customer 2 for NC.

I think, if I'm doing WHERE StateID = 'VA', for example, I can GROUP BY CustomerID and then COUNT.  But that means running it 50 times for each state.  Is there a way to subquery this or something so it runs once for each state?

Comment: More Recent or More Frequent ? Isn't clear what result you want.

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY here. I think you should address that problem first

Comment: What is your mysql version ? And how you handle ties ?

Comment: Sorry, I clarified the post.  Looking for most frequent.  I'm not worried about primary key.  This is just an example.  The actual problem I'm working with is way more complex.  This is just a simple example to illustrate the concept.  My actually data set is the result of a ton of INNER JOINS.  Mysql version is 5.7.28.

Comment: Not sure how to handle ties.  I don't think I'm worried about it too much.  If I can order the rows by count, I'm happy just using LIMIT to grab the top X rows.

Answer (score 1):

**Schema (MySQL v8.0)**

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
    (`CustomerID` varchar(10), `StateID` varchar(7))
;

INSERT INTO Table1
    (`CustomerID`, `StateID`)
VALUES
    ('1', 'MD'),
    ('1', 'VA'),
    ('1', 'MD'),
    ('2', 'NC'),
    ('2', 'NC'),
    ('3', 'MD'),
    ('3', 'VA'),
    ('3', 'NC')
;
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT *
FROM (
      SELECT StateID, CustomerID,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (partition by StateID  ORDER BY cnt DESC) as rn
      FROM (        
            SELECT StateID, CustomerID, count (*) as cnt
            FROM Table1
            GROUP BY StateID, CustomerID
           ) p
      )  q
WHERE q.rn = 1;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| StateID | CustomerID | rn  |
| ------- | ---------- | --- |
| MD      | 1          | 1   |
| NC      | 2          | 1   |
| VA      | 1          | 1   |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/oZc8UzmjDaKXaXeFCkQT1t/0)